throwing exception using java record in spring MVC
I need to validate user request.
for example.
public record UserRequest(
    String s1,
    String s2
){
    public UserRequest{
        if(s1 == null) throw new CustomException(); // throws "s1 or s2 should not be null at same time"
        if(s2 == null) throw new CustomException();
    }
}

@PostMapping("")
public void registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequest req){
     // register logic goes here..
}

Currently am using @RestControllerAdvice to handle above CustomException()
but here is my situation.
error occured with logs
2024-08-01 22:08:47.153 ERROR 72001 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.c.b.e.h.RestExceptionControllerHandler : Unknown Internal Exception Occurred

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.packages.package.UserReqeust]: Constructor threw exception
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.createObject(DataBinder.java:994)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.construct(DataBinder.java:903)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.construct(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.constructAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:182)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.packages.package.CustomException: s1 or s2 should not be null at same time
    at com.packages.package.UserRequest.<init>(UserRequest.java:5)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:210)


//my CustomException Handler
@ExceptionHandler({CustomException.class})
    @Nullable
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomException(CustomException ex, WebRequest request) throws Exception {
         log.error(ex);
         //return 440 responseCode;
    }

//my "broader" Exception Handler
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    @Nullable
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleGlobalException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) throws Exception {
          log.error("Unknown Internal Exception Occurred");
          log.error(ex);
          //return 500 responseCode;
    }

// expected result
{
    "responseCode": 440          //my predefined code for custom exception
}

// actual result
{
    "responseCode": 500.         //my predefined code, but for broader exception
}

now I can play a hunch that it outbreaks of BeanInstantiationException first, rather than my CustomException.
how do i throw CustomException in java record?
is there something that i misunderstood
i tried to relocate the exceptions to Controllers but.. i want more than that
what might be the best practice?
=== edit ===
The reason why I want to handle above CustomException in record is, that i thought that handling within record seems quiet reasonable for me. also it does not have to write bunch of if statements in controller/presentation layers.
thank you for your attention.

Can you share the code for CustomException? Does it give the correct response code when you throw it from a different class?

well yes. if it is thrown under Controller layers, it does what i expected. (as above)

Did you put status like this ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) in your @RestControllerAdvice method for handling that exception?

yes!
return new ResponseEntity(new ErrorResponse(responseCode, ex.getMessage()), headers, responseCode.getHttpStatus());

Too little information, also why are you throwing an exception anyway from that place. Add the full stacktrace, your exception handler and controller. Not as comments, edit your question instead.

If you throw an exception from the constructor then how did you catch it when new object is created?

i don't follow the "when new object is created". my intention was while creating UserRequest, if s1 or s2 is null, then throws CustomException, handles by handleCustomExceptionmethod. but  i guess my "broader" Exception handler handled the BeanInstantiationException
